# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146

Tags: php, html, mysql

**I receive this error:**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'u471047401_test.Categories' doesn't exist' in /home/u471047401/public_html/inc/blocks/sidebar.php:13 Stack trace: #0 /home/u471047401/public_html/inc/blocks/sidebar.php(13): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 /home/u471047401/public_html/index.php(6): require('/home/u47104740...') #2 {main} thrown in /home/u471047401/public_html/inc/blocks/sidebar.php on line 13
```

Here is my code:

```
<?
$cat = $_GET['cat'];
if( empty($cat) )
{
    $cat = 0;
}
$menu_query = ("
    SELECT cat_id, cat_name, parent_cat
    FROM Categories
    WHERE (cat_id = ? OR parent_cat = ?)");

$stm = $conn->prepare($menu_query);
$stm->execute(array($cat, $cat));
("u471047401_test.Categories");
$categories = $stm->fetchAll();

?>
<div class='col-4 col-lg-4 ' style='padding-left:0;'>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked well;">
<?  
foreach( $categories as $categories_row )
{
    $act = $categories_row['cat_id'] == $cat ? 'active' : '';
    echo"
    <li class={$act}>
        <a href='category.php?cat={$categories_row['cat_id']}'>
        {$categories_row['cat_name']}
        </a> 
      </li>";

    if($categories_row['cat_id'] == $cat && $categories_row['cat_id'] > 0)
    {
    $back_link = " <li> <a href='category.php?cat={$categories_row['parent_cat']}' title='Go back to previous category'>Back</a> </li>";
    }
}
?>  
    <?= $back_link ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: So what do you not understand about "Table 'u471047401_test.Categories' doesn't exist"?

Comment: `("u471047401_test.Categories");` This line is totally useless.

Comment: After removing the line, I still have the same error. How do I create that Table?

Comment: Are you really asking how to create a table? How exactly have you reached so far if you apparently don't even know what a database is?

Comment: This code is free on the internet.. I downloaded it.

Comment: It's weird it isn't working. Everybody knows that web sites reproduce like plants: you cut a code fragment, paste it somewhere else and wait until you get a full site. ;-P